# Import excel to mysql with multiple linked table

Tags: php, mysql, excel, import

My Database Structure

Products

Categories

category_products

I am using category_products to link Products and categories .

But i have a single excel with both the fields[Products , categories]

This is how we have done with Price Range , Colors etc.....

Can any one help to solve this easily as possible.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? You don't have a question here, you are asking others to solve your problem without even having attempted anything in the first place.

Comment: sorry, i didn't ask people to solve.I am asking people to help.without knowing anything how can i?.if you have any suggestion i will try.

Comment: See suggestion below.

Answer (score 2):

As per your comments above, I can point you in some direction to get you started.

1) Use a third party library to read Excel workbook/sheet

`Try this: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com - their download has PLENTY of examples`

2) After you managed to read the excel data into a PHP Array, now you can import data by iterating through the array into your DB.

`For MySQL database manipulation, I'd recommend this library: http://www.meekro.com/quickstart.php`

Comment: thank you for nice suggestion very clearly mention :)

Answer (score 1):

You should do it using your own importing script. Read the document fields and import to appropriate tables. There is no way to import in a single run.

Comment: Let me know if need further help